# Underclocking/undervolting AMD Opteron Processors to lower TDP rating

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, settings, opteron, server-settings

How does one safely lower the TDP rating of Opteron CPUs? I am willing to sacrifice some power, but wish to keep stability.

**Background:**
I have a [TYAN S4985 Motherboard](http://www.tyan.com/Motherboards_S4985-SI_S4985G3NR-SI) with 4 quad-core Opteron 8380 processors in a very well-ventilated case. I bought fanless pure-copper coolers that came with no TDP rating. They are normally used on [racks with Opteron 280s](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SGI-Rackable-Systems-C1000-1U-Half-Depth-Server-4GB-2x-AMD-Dual-Core-Opteron-280/271424633324?_trksid=p2050601.c100085.m2372&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140211132617%26meid%3D5454ad9a064d4815b326d74a7fe3db26%26pid%3D100085%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D271424660497%26clkid%3D7041257725293344291&_qi=RTM2067268) (TDP ratings of ~90W). My processors are rated at 115W TDP. I'm a little worried about installing them and keeping the 115W rating, so can anyone please shine some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Fanless heatsinks from servers are designed to have a strong forced airflow passed over them from fans in the case.  They will not be enough in a more spacious case.

Answer (score 0):

https://sites.google.com/site/k10stat/ can undervolt, based on each P-state. Changing clocking is possible, but only when your hardware allows it.

It supports a wide variety of AMD processors.

You will need to run it automatically (e. g. task scheduler) since it only changes settings for the current session.